# TexLive 2018 Installation Error: Missing lz4

Tags: texlive

Here is an error message for TexLive 2018 installation for Windows 10. Please advise.

```
PATH=C:\Users\A517-51G-54L4\Downloads\install-tl\install-tl-20180520\tlpkg\tlperl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\Users\A517-51G-54L4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
"C:\Users\A517-51G-54L4\Downloads\install-tl\install-tl-20180520\install-tl" -gui perltk
TeXLive::TLUtils::setup_programs (w32) failed at C:/Users/A517-51G-54L4/Downloads/install-tl/install-tl-20180520/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2347.
C:\Users\A517-51G-54L4\Downloads\install-tl\install-tl-20180520\tlpkg\installer\lz4\lz4.exe --version failed (status 256): No such file or directory
Output is:
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\A517-51G-54L4\Downloads\install-tl\install-tl-20180520\install-tl: Goodbye.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: this has been raised on the texlive list and should be fixed at the next update

Comment: For the record, the report in the texlive mailing list is http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-May/041787.html. I wonder when the next update will arrive, but apparently this issue is starting to hit more users (e.g., https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/45). As of this time, the installer still has the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem today.

Comment: Same problem today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My fault, some code for testing during development remain on commit.
Should be fixed with today's installer. Please grab a new copy.

PS: Thanks for the comments, indeed the Windows installer was broken. That should be fixed today (2018-05-23). Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: To avoid obvious mistakes like this, perhaps you can consider using continuous integration in the future (such as AppVeyor).

Comment: Is it really fixed? I'm still getting the same error for both the .exe and the .zip, although I got a copy from a mirror that had a 5/21 timestamp on the files, so the mirror itself appears properly updated.

Comment: As of this time, I still get the same error, so "Should be fixed with today's installer" does not seem to be true yet.

Comment: It seems you were trying to fix the problem for *nix: https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm?r1=47777&r2=47784 but the OP was using Windows, and the Windows installer is still broken. It will be great if you could actually test it by yourself before releasing it in public.

Comment: @KarlHagen @YihuiXie can you post the output of `install-tl -v`?

Comment: Not necessary anymore, found the problem ...

Comment: Not sure if the following is the result of the same issue: `<path to>/texmf.cnf not found: No such file or directory at <uncompressed dir path>`, but the installation fails

Comment: Using the new build I get warnings like this:
`tlpkg\installer\xz\xz.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Upon checking the xz directory, I indeed see no file called xz.exe. There is an xzdec.exe file, but renaming that one to xz.exe will result in the warning
`tlpkg\installer\xz\xz.exe: unknown option -- f`.

Comment: Ignoring the xz.exe warnings, I also end up with the `texmf.cnf not found` error, which aborts the installation :-(  Sorry to ask this, but did the developer test his own installation package at all?

Comment: @norbert, the 2018-05-23 installer appears to be broken still on Windows and macOS 10.11–10.13 (all the error messages are about xz missing). Is it possible to revert to the pre–May 20 installer? For what it’s worth, I second @YihuiZie’s suggestion about continuous integration, and I can try to make a pull request for this if I knew where the repository was hosted.

Comment: The current installer is still broken (`xz` not found). @norbert Basically there are three ways to test software: 1) practically test it by yourself; 2) test it automatically via continuous integration on the cloud; 3) let (a large number of) users test it. I think the option #3 is the worst and often too late, and #2 is the best. If #2 is not possible, at least #1 should be done. I really wish we could stop the loop of "should be fixed" + "still broken".

Comment: Thanks for educating me, but trust me, I know about CI. I have set up CI for our *binary* *source* tree. But the main TL repository is in svn and about 15Gb. Tell me *ANY* CI system that can deal with that!?!? We already test a lot of things, and all the critical changes in the tlmgr go through special repositories and testing for weeks before being released to the public. Only the installer is always based on the latest sources, and thus might break. But since it is rebuilt every night we don't consider this such a problem. If you are in such a hurry, grab the .iso and install from there.

Comment: Ah and yes, tomorrow's installer *should* contain the xz binary for windows ...

Comment: @norbert, [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com) has a disk usage quota of about 80 GB, I believe, and by deleting large directories containing unneeded files (in this case C:\cygwin and C:\Qt, probably), staying under that quota should be possible (although downloading the repository may not be). At any rate, for just testing the installer, I think it should be possible to run a minimal installation just to make sure the installer works.

Comment: @Nate all development and management is done on Linux, so testing a Windows installer would require setting up Wine on a server, something I'm not planning to do for now. We are fixing the installer whenever it breaks, and fixes will be in immediately. This is different from tlmgr where we can break there while system beyond repair.

Comment: @norbert Setting up AppVeyor only to test the installer on Windows may take two minutes. If you create a Github repo and enable AppVeyor, I can send you a pull request so that you can test the TL installer by simply clicking a button in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, the installer still seems to be broken. Here is the logs on AppVeyor: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/yihui/tinytex/build/1.0.6 (`'...tlpkg\installer\xz\xz.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command`).

Comment: @YihuiXie Strange, the install-tl.zip I am using contains tlpkg/installer/xz/xz.exe. Which file did you use?
I have now created a github project only with the unpacked installer, https://github.com/TeX-Live/installer if you can send me a appveor.yml or a pull request, that would help. Thanks

Comment: @YihuiXie you are using the 20180523 installer, you need to use the 20180524 one.

Comment: @YihuiXie ok I copied parts from your project and I am trying to install on appveyor now. Will see what is the problem.

Comment: Ok, found the problem - more fun to come. WIll try to fix it tonight.

Comment: Ok, last comment for now. Installer is fixed, at least it did run to completion on the AppVeyor after the fixes I made.
That means starting with 20180525 installer version should be ok ... hopefully ;-)

Comment: @norbert Sounds great! So it seems we just need to wait for one more day or two before http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip is updated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the main mirrors of CTAN will have the changes tomorrow (in about 10h), the others depending on their rsync schedule.

Comment: In fact, it is postponed another day :-( I only commited it to the installer git repo and not to upstream svn -- how stupid. 20180526 it will (hopefully) be.

Answer (score 4):

1. First run install-tl-windows.exe and select unpack only.
2. Then go to [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/releases) and download windows binaries.
3. Make new folder named `lz4` in `<path to your extracted folder>/tlpkg/installer/`
4. Extract zipped file from [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/releases) into it.
5. Download prebuild binaries from [xz](https://tukaani.org/xz/).
6. Copy files from `bin_x86-64` folder (zip file from [xz](https://tukaani.org/xz/)) into `<path to your extracted folder>/tlpkg/installer/xz`
7. Run `install-tl-advanced.bat` or `install-tl-windows.bat`

Hope this works for you too.